# MySql view mixes collations but all tables/columns are utf8_unicode_ci

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use a `view` I've created that has several joins. The database, all the tables and all the columns are set to utf8_unicode_ci (I've checked and double checked).

However, the resulting `view` is using utf8_general_ci for a (seemingly random) set of columns from a particular table: not all of them, just one or two, even though they are all set to utf8_unicode_ci.

This is giving an `Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and (utf8_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE)` error when querying the view.

The database is on Amazon RDS (in case that makes any difference). How can I ensure the view has all columns set to the same collation?

Answer (score 0):

Mystery solved... it turns out I was using a custom function to apply uppercase on the first letter of words in some columns. This was resulting in the change in collation.

It may be possible to alter the function so it doesn't screw with the collation, but for now I'm just not using it.